# Extend avro field with extra annotations/metadata

Tags: avro

Sometimes is usefull to give a contextual information to a field.

Other protocols like protobuf support annotations through what they call [Option](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#customoptions) which allows the following customization (uuid field annotation):

```
message FarmerRegisteredEvent {

  string uuid = 1[(pi2schema.subject_identifier) = true];

  oneof personalData {
    ContactInfo contactInfo = 2;
    pi2schema.EncryptedPersonalData encryptedPersonalData = 6;
  }

  google.protobuf.Timestamp registeredAt = 4;
  string referrer = 5;

}
```

Would it be possible to add such metadata information in a avro schema?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via [JsonProperties](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.avro/avro/1.9.2/org/apache/avro/JsonProperties.html) because Avro schema is JSON.

Following example adds property into Avro Schema to give [BigQuery type hint](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro#extract_json_data_from_avro_data)

```
var stringSchema = Schema.create(Schema.Type.STRING)
stringSchema.addProp("sqlType", "JSON")
```